# Теряется ссылка на изображение при переходе на страницу. React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Сделал роутинг для страниц через Outlet, в котором есть блоки Navigation, main и footer. В навигации лежит ссылка на изображение, которое в ней отображается. Пока есть три страницы, пути которых: /, /services /services/:order. Компоненты соответственно лежат в папках src/Components/MainPage/MainPage.jsx, src/Components/ServicesPage/ServicesPage.jsx src/Components/ServicesPage/ServiceOrder/ServiceOrder.jsx.
Проблема в том, что изображение в навигации отображается на главной странице и странице services, но если перейти на страницу serviceOrder и обновить страницу, то картинка пропадает (вместо неё появляется альтернативный текст). Почему ссылка теряется и как это исправить?

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/...`} alt=""/>
```

Попробуйте такую конструкцию, я решал похожую проблему